# how to understand this code from Random Waypoint model

Tags: c++, ns-3

I am new to C++, but here is a piece of code from Random waypoint.This is the refernce of it:  http://netdb.cis.upenn.edu/rapidnet/doxygen/html/classns3_1_1_random_waypoint_mobility_model.html#a2b8fc7b2cf1e2ffec7e6c6a9d5f7404

> Says:This method returns the TypeId associated to
>   ns3::RandomWaypointMobilityModel.

But I have no idea how to use it(update: how to call the attribute of this model)?

```
TypeId
RandomWaypointMobilityModel::GetTypeId (void)
{
   static TypeId tid = TypeId ("ns3::RandomWaypointMobilityModel")
   .SetParent<MobilityModel> () 
   .SetGroupName ("Mobility") 
   .AddConstructor<RandomWaypointMobilityModel> ()
   .AddAttribute ("Speed",  //name
               "A random variable used to pick the speed of a random waypoint model.",  //help context
               StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0.3|Max=0.7]"),
               MakePointerAccessor (&RandomWaypointMobilityModel::m_speed), //setup(initailize m_speed)
               MakePointerChecker<RandomVariableStream> ()) 
   .AddAttribute ("Pause",  
               "A random variable used to pick the pause of a random waypoint model.", //help context
               StringValue ("ns3::ConstantRandomVariable[Constant=2.0]"),
               MakePointerAccessor (&RandomWaypointMobilityModel::m_pause),
               MakePointerChecker<RandomVariableStream> ())
  .AddAttribute ("PositionAllocator",
               "The position model used to pick a destination point.",
               PointerValue (),
               MakePointerAccessor (&RandomWaypointMobilityModel::m_position),
               MakePointerChecker<PositionAllocator> ());

return tid;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about it? It returns a type `TypeId` which is a class - where is the problem?

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks for replying, there is no problem of this code, just want to understand more about it. For example how can I use the attributes inside of RandomWaypointMobilityModel?

Comment: @UnholySheep and I know exactly what it returns, it's very clear on the code.

Comment: The reference you linked states that it is a `static` function, so you call it like `RandomWaypointMobilityModel::GetTypeId();`

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes, that's correct. It worked.
`
[ 932/2423] Compiling scratch/rwpmodel.cc
[2417/2423] Linking build/scratch/rwpmodel
[2418/2423] Linking build/scratch/scratch-simulator
[2418/2423] Linking build/scratch/third
[2422/2423] Linking build/scratch/subdir/subdir
[2423/2423] Linking build/scratch/test
 build/compile_commands.json
'build' finished successfully (4.215s)
`
So, yeah thank you! @UnholySheep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saying you want to understand the code I want to point you to the ns-3 tutorial which explains how their attribute system works (https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/index.html), but I will try to give you a gist of it and point you to an example:

### How to use the ns3 attribute system

1. As you did, the first step when you want to set an attribute value is to look up the class documentation which tells you how to set the attribute with the bullet point labeled 'Set with class' (i.e. `RandomVariableValue` in your case)
2. You can then create an object of your class of interest (here: `RandomWaypointMobilityModel`) via an ns3 Helper, where you can set the attribute with the help of the information that you looked up in step one.

### A short example

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"

using namespace ns3;

static void 
CourseChange (std::string foo, Ptr<const MobilityModel> mobility)
{
  Vector pos = mobility->GetPosition ();
  Vector vel = mobility->GetVelocity ();
  std::cout << Simulator::Now () << ", model=" << mobility << ", POS: x=" << pos.x << ", y=" << pos.y
            << ", z=" << pos.z << "; VEL:" << vel.x << ", y=" << vel.y
            << ", z=" << vel.z << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  CommandLine cmd;
  cmd.Parse (argc, argv);

  NodeContainer c;
  c.Create (1);

  // Position allocator for the start of the simulation
  MobilityHelper mobility;
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::RandomDiscPositionAllocator",
                                 "X", StringValue ("100.0"),
                                 "Y", StringValue ("100.0"),
                                 "Rho", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=30]"));

  // The position allocator that will be used by the RandomWaypointMobilityModel
  GridPositionAllocator posAllocator;
  posAllocator.SetMinX(0.0);
  posAllocator.SetMinY(0.0);
  posAllocator.SetDeltaX(5.0);
  posAllocator.SetDeltaY(5.0);
  posAllocator.SetLayoutType(ns3::GridPositionAllocator::ROW_FIRST);

  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::RandomWaypointMobilityModel",
                             "PositionAllocator", PointerValue(&posAllocator));

  mobility.InstallAll ();
  Config::Connect ("/NodeList/*/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange",
                   MakeCallback (&CourseChange));

  Simulator::Stop (Seconds (500.0));

  Simulator::Run ();

  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

Here you can see a long example with a full description how those concepts mesh together:
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/building-topologies.html#building-a-wireless-network-topology

Comment: Another hint: Add the ns-3 tag to your question so that community members with ns-3 experience can find your question easily.

Comment: and by the way I think we need to build more examples about how to use the models in ns-3 communities for the beginer to learn.

Comment: No problem, by the way do you know how to run the random waypoint model?